# How can I specify ime options for soft keyboard when not using editview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

In my application, I am showing/hiding the keyboard to allow the user to manipulate a custom widget. There is no `EditText` that has focus.

The problem I am having is that I want the layout to adjust in size when the keyboard shows. This is normally done by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity tag in the manifest. This *does* work when the device (currently the 7in Galaxy Tab running 2.2) is in portrait mode but when rotated to landscape, the layout does not adjust size and the keyboard hides half the screen.

Now, I noticed that if instead I use an EditView that has  `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`, the layout resizes appropriately. Is there any way to achieve the same effect on a keyboard displayed through a window token?

Adding a hidden EditView to the screen is not ideal since it will change the implementation rather drastically.

For reference, here is the code I use to show the keyboard within the custom widget.

```
    mInputMethod = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mInputMethod.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    requestFocus();
    setOnKeyListener(this);
```

and to hide.

```
    mInputMethod.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
    setOnKeyListener(null);
```